# How does one see current enumerators holding the connection open in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

Trying to diagnose the dreaded Entity Framework error of "New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session", clearly there's an enumerator still operating on the connection, but I've ToList() just about all of them already.  I'm guessing theres a Lazy Loading proxy object holding the connection hostage.

I'm running into the error while foreach'ing over a ToList() collection, trying to run a sproc with output param using `dbcontext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` and getting the exception.

I'm wondering, is there a way to interrogate the DbContext to find out what enumerator(s) are currently operating on the current connection? (Or more precisely the DbContext.Database.Connection)

Answer (score 0):

You may use ADO.Net performance counters to monitor the connections at the server. It provides around 10 different sets of counters for analysis. Details documentation can be found at

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/performance-counters

Another option is to start SQL profiler and monitor the statements get executed and the connections happen at the server in real time